# Android: Removing all previous activities from the stack

Tags: android

This question has been answered numerous times it seems, but none of the answers solve the problem for me, so I thought I'd ask a new one.

My scenario is as follows:
I have added a navigation drawer to my app that holds list items for each section of the app. Tapping one of these launches the appropriate activity for that app section.

The way I wanted to do this was to have a main activity which had the drawer layout and then everything else would be fragments, but the app has a lot of activities already and the customer isn't willing to pay for the extra time that would be needed to convert these to fragments and get it all working. Therefore I'm keeping it as it is and have the nav drawer on each activity.

When the user clicks an item in the nav drawer, that section's activity is launched. If the user presses the back button on any of the activities that the drawer brings them to, I want the app to close (and go back to the Android app menu or home screen or whatever).

My problem is that pressing back will just pop the activity that the user was previously on when they clicked an item from the drawer. For example:

1. User is in Activity A.
2. User opens drawer and clicks list item.
3. Activity B is opened.
4. User presses the back button.
5. Activity A is shown.

I'm looking for a way to remove all previous activities from the stack, so that when a nav item is clicked, everything already in the stack is removed so that pressing back on the new activity will end the app because there won't be anything else to show.

The closest I've got is using the **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** and **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK** flags on the intent that is launched on the nav list item click.

```
sectionIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
parentActivity.startActivity(sectionIntent);
```

(where sectionIntent is an Intent for the new activity and parentActivity is the activity hosting the drawer).

This actually works, but an empty (black) screen is displayed for half a second or so between the old activity closing and the new one showing.

I've also considered using LocalBroadcastManager to tell all activities to close when a "top level" (as such) activity is exited, but to be honest that approach seems like total overkill to me and surely a simpler option must exist?!

Does anyone know a way either to prevent this delay (like for the previous activities to be removed AFTER the new one appears) or another way to remove the activities in the stack?

Thanks in advance, fellow devs :)

-- SOLUTION --

Thanks to one of @Zielony 's suggestions, I managed to get this working.

I made a base top level activity and made it send a local broadcast to exit the app.

```
public class AppSectionHomeActivity extends BaseActivity {
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    sendFinishActivityBroadcast();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    sendFinishActivityBroadcast();
    super.finish();
}

private void sendFinishActivityBroadcast() {
    // Send a local broadcast to all other activities to tell them to close.
    Log.d("AppSectionHomeActivity.sendFinishActivityBroadcast", "Sending broadcast");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Constants.EXIT_APP);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

I then made a base activity for all other activities (the ones that weren't top level ones) so make them listen for the broadcast and then call finish() on themselves if they received it.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
// A broadcast receiver so that we can listen out for feed updated events.
private BroadcastReceiver exitAppReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        unregisterReceiver();
        // When the activity receives the broadcast to finish up, then do so.
        finish();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(exitAppReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.EXIT_APP));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void unregisterReceiver() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(exitAppReceiver);
}
```

}

This seems to work!

Comment: You can kill process when exiting top level Activity but I guess it's too much aggression ;)

Comment: Aye @Zielony, I read that I could do that but a lot of people were saying it was bad form. Also, the app caches some stuff it gets from an API so I'd prefer not to totally kill it as this would be lost I'd imagine.

Comment: not really. You can kill the app after saving all data and doing some cleanup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several choices:

- use Broadcast to tell the stack to close itself and then add new Activity. It's quite good solution, but seems like you tried something similiar. Also, this shows best that you shouldn't attempt to close multiple activities. I don't know the thought process behind that.
- use Process.kill() to kill your application when exiting most recent top-level Activity. It would look like exiting the app without the rest of the stack. It's not that bad either - Android will close unused Activities anyway, so it's not that resource demanding.
- use Fragment stacks. I know your client wants you to do it quick and cheap, but fragment stacks are really good for this.
- use Tasks to group Activities and close groups at once. Seems like it's not working for you and I don't really know why. This is the pre-fragment solution for your case.

Comment: Thanks @Zielony. The grouping the activities together sounds promising! I hadn't actually tried the broadcast approach. It seems like it would work, but it just seemed like overkill. I'll give it a whirl too though.

Comment: I ended up using the broadcast approach so that all other activities were closed when one of the top level activities was closed. Thanks @Zielony!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using fragments instead of activities? This allows a lot more flexibility when things will be shown/hidden/available etc.

Are you using a new nav drawer for each activity?

Comment: Yeah I'm using a new nav drawer for each activity (although I have the code to create this in a helper class). I wasn't sure how else to have something that was common to all screens other than using fragments.
I wanted to re-write the whole thing using fragments (the app was originally written in pre-Honeycomb times) but I was blocked on doing this because it would be quite a hefty re-write! Bad times :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. such as

```
sectionIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
parentActivity.startActivity(sectionIntent);
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks @kablu. I had tried that before (it was on a few other posts) but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest file, which ever activity you don't want in stack, in that activity make this changes

```
 android:noHistory="true"
```

I hope this works for you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @Ajinkya S. However, I didn't want to do this because some activities have other activities that are called from them and I wanted the ability to go back from them.

Comment: then OnBackPressed() implement your Intent to that particular activity.